# Creating a publication-ready table in R, with groups as nested columns

Tags: r, grouping, gtsummary

I have been using R for a number of years but increasingly need to produce elegant tables for publications. My preference is to have R do this for me but was never able to devote the time to learn this and always ended up editing tables in Word.

I am currently trying to produce a pretty looking summary stats table of incident reports using the gtsummary package. My data is almost 150k rows and it contains the following (simplified):

```
Year <- c('2016','2017','2018','2016','2017','2018')
Type <- c('Fall','Concussion','Fall','Burn','Burn','Laceration')
Service <- c('Hospital','Hospital','Nursing home','Hospital','Trauma centre','Hospital')
Risk <- c(6,10,3,15,3,6)
dat <- cbind.data.frame(Year,Type,Service,Risk)
```

What I want to produce is a table using gtsummary where the rows are 'Type', the columns are grouped by Service and then by Year, and the data showing in the table cells is the mean Risk.

So far, I have been able to produce the table in the exact structure I want but I cannot figure out how to specify that the value in the cells should be the mean of Risk. Here's the code that will produce the above:

```
data %>%
  select(c(Type,Service,Risk,Year)) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = Service,
    ~ .x %>%
      tbl_summary(by = Year, missing = "no")))
```

To be clear, I would like the table to have the following structure:

[image]

Would appreciate any pointers on this as i've tried everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you are after using the `tbl_continuous()` function. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.1'

Year <- c('2016','2017','2018','2016','2017','2018')
Type <- c('Fall','Concussion','Fall','Burn','Burn','Laceration')
Service <- c('Hospital','Hospital','Nursing home','Hospital','Trauma centre','Hospital')
Risk <- c(6,10,3,15,3,6)
dat <- 
  cbind.data.frame(Year,Type,Service,Risk) |> 
  # filling in so each cell has at least one value
  tidyr::complete(Year,Type,Service, fill = list(Risk = 1))

tbl <-
  dat %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = Service,
    ~ .x %>%
      tbl_continuous(
        by = Year, 
        variable = Risk,
        include = Type,
        statistic = ~"{mean}"
      ) |> 
      modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-05-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Oh thanks, this is much closer to what I want. However, i'm getting an error when I try this with my own code:

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `tbl = switch(...)`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `df_stats = pmap(...)`.
Caused by error in `pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `left_join()`:
! Can't join `x$by_fct` with `y$by_fct` due to incompatible types.
ℹ `x$by_fct` is a <integer>.
ℹ `y$by_fct` is a <factor<0de69>>.


Apologies for poor formatting above.

Comment: Unless you can provide data to replicate your error, there is not much anyone can do to assist, unfortunately.

Comment: The tbl object is class gtsummary, which has a special print method to generate the table when it's printed to the console or a Quarto doc for example.

Comment: I figured it out, my year variable was integer format, changed it to character and it's now sorted. Thank you very much for taking the time to solve this!